# Absolute element jQuery centering issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, centering

What I'm trying to do is to center horizontally `.buttons-wrapper` which is an `display: absolute` element with jQuery (centering it with CSS doesn't work because it wraps up elements inside `.buttons-wrapper` when there is plenty of space left). The problem is that when I add margin-right to the `.btn` class elements to space them up a little bit they are a moved more to the right than perfectly centered. How can I fix that so `.buttons-wrapper` will be perfectly centered and `.btn` elements will be spaced?

@NOTE: I don't know why but the snippet doesn't work properly, but it works perfectly fine on my computer.

@NOTE2: I know that can be solved with flexbox, but the solution has to be IE 9+ supported, and Flexbox is not supported by IE at all.
http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

```js
$(function() {
    $('.buttons-wrapper').css({
        'margin-left' : function() {return -$(this).outerWidth()/2},
    });
});
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; }

.slides, .slide1, .slide2, .slide3 {
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  position: relative;
  display: none; }
  .slides h1, .slide1 h1, .slide2 h1, .slide3 h1 {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 2em;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 4.25em;
    font-weight: bold; }

.slide1 {
  background: url("images/backgrounds/slider1.jpg") center/cover; }

.slide2 {
  background: url("images/backgrounds/slider2.jpg") center/cover; }

.slide3 {
  background: url("images/backgrounds/slider3.jpg") center/cover; }

.buttons-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150px;
  left: 50%; }

.btn {
  display: inline;
  opacity: 0.75;
  margin-right: 2.208333333333333em; }
  .btn:hover {
    opacity: 1; }
  .btn a {
    display: inline-block; }
  .btn .paragraph {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.5em;
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 220px; }
  .btn .button-red {
    background-color: #c43434; }
  .btn .button-blue {
    background-color: #428e9e; }
  .btn .button-green {
    background-color: #4f8a60; }
  .btn img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="header">
  <div class="slide1 active">
    <h1>Slide no. 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="slide2">
    <h1>Slide no. 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="slide3">
    <h1>Slide no. 3</h1>
  </div>
<!-- end of slides -->
<!-- slider buttons part -->
  <div class="buttons-wrapper">
    <div class="btn">
      <a href="http://facebook.com">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/81x81" alt="typo-icon"><!-- this comment is just to fix the gap between image and paragraph
        --><p class="paragraph button-red">Slide no. 1</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <a href="http://facebook.com">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/81x81" alt="rwd-icon"><!-- this comment is just to fix the gap between image and paragraph
        --><p class="paragraph button-blue">Slide no. 2</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <a href="http://facebook.com">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/81x81" alt="ux-icon"><!-- this comment is just to fix the gap between image and paragraph
        --><p class="paragraph button-green">Slide no. 3</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- end of slider buttons -->
</section>
```

Comment: The snippet doesn't work because an include for jQuery is missing from the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need jQuery to do this. You can use `transform: translateX()` which is supported in IE9 with a `-ms` prefix - http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

And you can use `:nth-child()` to remove the `margin-right` from the 2nd button (the one on the right) so that only the buttons on the left have a margin, creating space between the buttons. You can also add a unique class to each of those elements to target individual ones.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.slides,
.slide1,
.slide2,
.slide3 {
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

.slides h1,
.slide1 h1,
.slide2 h1,
.slide3 h1 {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 4.25em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.slide1 {
  background: url("images/backgrounds/slider1.jpg") center/cover;
}

.slide2 {
  background: url("images/backgrounds/slider2.jpg") center/cover;
}

.slide3 {
  background: url("images/backgrounds/slider3.jpg") center/cover;
}

.buttons-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.btn {
  display: inline;
  opacity: 0.75;
  margin-right: 2.208333333333333em;
}
  
.btn:nth-child(2) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn .paragraph {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.5em;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 220px;
}

.btn .button-red {
  background-color: #c43434;
}

.btn .button-blue {
  background-color: #428e9e;
}

.btn .button-green {
  background-color: #4f8a60;
}

.btn img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<section id="header">
  <div class="slide1 active">
    <h1>Slide no. 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="slide2">
    <h1>Slide no. 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="slide3">
    <h1>Slide no. 3</h1>
  </div>
<!-- end of slides -->
<!-- slider buttons part -->
  <div class="buttons-wrapper">
    <div class="btn">
      <a href="http://facebook.com">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/81x81" alt="typo-icon"><!-- this comment is just to fix the gap between image and paragraph
        --><p class="paragraph button-red">Slide no. 1</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <a href="http://facebook.com">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/81x81" alt="rwd-icon"><!-- this comment is just to fix the gap between image and paragraph -->
<p class="paragraph button-blue">Slide no. 2</p>
</a>
</div>
    <div class="btn">
      <a href="http://facebook.com">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/81x81" alt="ux-icon"><!-- this comment is just to fix the gap between image and paragraph
        --><p class="paragraph button-green">Slide no. 3</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- end of slider buttons -->
</section>
```

Comment: I know that it could be solved with transform: translateX, but as I've said - When I do this, `.btn` elements wrap and stack on each other even when there is plenty of space left on the right and left side. That's why I used jQuery and margin-left.

Comment: @TomaszCzechowski does this behave how you want? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oZowLN

Comment: Well, not really. The text inside the buttons has to be left-aligned. @EDIT: added `text-align: left` to .btn and it works just fine. Thank you!